# C++/CLI targetting .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c++, winforms, .net-core, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

.NET Core 3.1 added support for C++/CLI ([Announcing .NET Core 3.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-1/)). The official announcement lists two new project templates, *CLR Class Library (.NET Core)* and *CLR Empty Project (.NET Core)*, which we can indeed find and use.

However, there is no additional information about supporting technologies such as WPF or Windows Forms. In [a blog posts in September](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-future-of-cpp-cli-and-dotnet-core-3/), Microsoft said:

> we are committed to supporting C++/CLI for .NET Core to enable easy
>   interop between C++ codebases and .NET technologies such as WPF and
>   Windows Forms. This support isn’t going to be ready when .NET Core 3.0
>   first ships, but it will be available in .NET Core 3.1 which ships
>   with Visual Studio 2019 16.4

Using Visual Studio 2019 16.4.x and targeting .NET Core 3.1, I have tried to create a demo WinForms app using C++/CLI. However, it does not work.

First of all, C++/CLI projects targeting .NET Core must be DLLs:

> error NETSDK1116: C++/CLI projects targeting .NET Core must be dynamic
>   libraries.

So I tried keeping the Win Forms code in a C++/CLI DLL compiled with `/clr:netcore` and running it from a native app. However, I get a runtime exception:

> Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format. File name:
>   'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' ---> System.BadImageFormatException:
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   (0x8007000B)

I have referenced in the C++/CLI project the **System.Windows.Forms.dll** from c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.0\, which is the location of the **Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0** runtime.

Is this supposed to work and I'm not doing something right?

Comment: I am encountering related problems with my own C++/CLI dll and targeting .NET  Core 3.1, I found a number of problems.  Filed a bug report for one of them.   I was able to leave the C++/CLI targeting .NET Framework 4.8 and only have my  client  C# app target .NET Core 3.1, but then I started getting the exceptions like what you are getting, and even weirder only in DEBUG builds. I suspect MS has some work to do.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with my simple sample of .NET Core C# executable using the C++/CLI (managed C++) .Net Core DLL. Eventually figured out that I needed to explicitly set my C# executable target from **Any CPU** to **x64**. Most of the time it comes down to 32 bit / 64 bit mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I found this document on the microsoft's website.
It explains how to do it, and is accompanied by a github repo you can easily clone and try out yourself:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/porting-a-c-cli-project-to-net-core/